# JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, callback

I am making application using phonegap in android. I am using cordova 1.6.1

I am getting this error when i call html file from my javascript callback function.:

> JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks

i am calling html file using

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/html/sync.html");
```

I have also tried to call html using `window.location = "../html/sync.html";` but it gives me same error..I have all the permission required to use internet in menifest.

Comment: If you use jQuery-mobile you can try `$.mobile.changePage('url');`

Comment: @antyrat sorry..i am not using it..

Comment: how about `window.location.replace('url')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

> I created inline script in my html page and in that script i called first login method then i called html calling line.by this way i have achieved success callback and redirected to html page.

here is the code:

```
function  loginfunc()
{
    loginV();

    console.log("before loadUrl:");
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('UserId') != -1)
    {
        window.location.replace('../html/sync.html');
    }
}
```